# How likely is a reform on the status of 'developing' country pushed by the Trump adminstration only affect China?

Tags: international-relations, international-law, china, international

https://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-trade-wto/trump-targets-china-in-call-for-wto-to-reform-developing-country-status-idUSKCN1UL2G6

The Trump administration is trying to weaken China using any mean necessary.

> U.S. President Donald Trump put pressure on the World Trade
>   Organization on Friday to change how it designates developing
>   countries, **singling out China for unfairly getting preferential
>   treatment**.

Lately, it has put pressure on the WTO to do just that, but how likely is a reform on the status of 'developing' country only affect China? Will it likely impact other countries such as Mexico, Turkey, India, South Africa, Russia and Brazil?